OneDrive for business connector gives 'The SSL connection could not be established' error
I am using the Create file action from OneDrive for Business logic app standard connectors. While everything works fine in my local environment, I get the The SSL connection could not be established error while trying it out on Azure.
I can see that it is making an API call to the following endpoint https://ec5cee1458623d38.18.common.logic-northeurope.azure-apihub.net:443/apim/onedriveforbusiness/dcc8db565c394cc2bde64296ac5044b9/datasets/default/files?folderPath=*sanitized*&name=*sanitized*' and I also tried to get the certificates using the method shown here and using thumbprint in WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES but it still gives the same error.
I am unsure if I am getting/using the right certificates as I have tried plenty of them. How to get them for https://ec5cee1458623d38.18.common.logic-northeurope.azure-apihub.net? When I run the powershell given in the above link, it gives me the following error but generates one certificate.

I plan to start the troubleshooting by using the traces mentioned in the above link but wanted to know if there is an easy way out.

Since the logic app was behind a VNET, the solution is to add a user-defined route for AzureConnectors service tag with the next hop as the internet.
